# How to solve equations using R

Tags: r

i would like to equate "dum1" and "dum2" to 5 & 1.5 respectively and solve those two equations and get the values for "alp" and "lam". The following is the R code, but the error pops up. 
"Error in fun(x, ...) : argument "lam" is missing, with no default"
Could anyone please help me to solve it?

```
F<-function(alp,lam){
dum1=((1/lam)*(digamma(alp+1)-digamma(1)))
dum2=((1/lam^2)*(psigamma(1)-psigamma(alp+1)))

return(c(dum1-5,dum2-1.5))
}

x<-fsolve(F,c(0,2))
```

Comment: From which package is fsolve()?

Comment: Does F(alp = 0, lam = 2) work? (Also you shouldn't name your function F)

Comment: From looking in to the function (from `pracma` package), looks like the input to function F (agree that should be re-named as clashes with shorthand for FALSE) takes just a single input. So change it to be something like `function(x){ alp=x[1] .. lam=x[2] .. }` where you have a single input and then in the function extract the relevant parts. This gives a different error for me, but looks like a genuine package error, rather than just a mistake with the inputs

Comment: Thank you so much for your inputs, but still im getting the error                       
 "Error in fun(x, ...) : argument "lam" is missing, with no default"

Comment: It's a fuction from "pracma " package